# why use not gate to build driver and receiver

Tags: driver, receiver

I am reading the book [Digital Design and Computer Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128200642). In this book, it describes logic levels that map of a continuous variable onto a discrete binary variable. and it introduces two gates called driver and receiver. The output of the driver is connected to the input of the receiver.

Here is what the book says:

*The mapping of a continuous variable onto a discrete binary variable is done  by  defining  logic  levels,  as  shown  in  Figure  1. The  first  gate  is  called the driver and the second gate is called the receiver. The output of the driver is connected to the input of the receiver.*

*A  real  inverter  changes  more  gradually  between  the  extremes,  as shown  in  Figure  2. When  the  input  voltage  V(A)  is  0,  the  output voltage  V(Y)  =  VDD. When V(A)  =  VDD,  V(Y)  =  0. However,  the  transition  between  these  endpoints  is  smooth  and  may  not  be  centered  at  exactly VDD/2. This raises the question of how to define the logic levels.A  reasonable  place  to  choose  the  logic  levels  is  where  the  slope  of  the  transfer  characteristic  dV(Y)/dV(A)  is  −1.  These  two  points  are  called  the  unity  gain  points.  Choosing  logic  levels  at  the  unity
gain  points  usually  maximizes  the  noise  margins.  If  VIL  were  reduced,  VOH would only increase by a small amount. But if VIL were increased, VOH would drop precipitously.*

My question is why we use NOT gate to build driver and receiver?

Is it aimed to amplify the signal? If it isn't, why not just connnect the output of a device to the input of the other device?

[image: diver and receiver]

[image: behavior of these two gates]

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. This contains little detail to explain what you are asking. It's a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: okay, I will add more information. thx

Comment: To help, specify, at least, at "what" cases this Question is related ... Distance between driver and receiver ... etc ...

Comment: Thanks for the good effort to clarify. Please can edit further and add the actual text that makes this statement. Otherwise, it's wanting everyone to go and look it up somewhere in the book.

Comment: As TonyM says you should quote the actual lines, paragraph from the text.  Also as Antonio51 states, you should consider distance between driver and receiver, as in 10cm, 1m, 10m, etc.

Comment: thanks for your kind, TonyM. so it is really aimed to amplify the signal, right? The reason why not use buffer to amplify the signal is because cmos is an inverter and we need 2 cmos if we use buffer?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why we use NOT gate to build driver and receiver?

To me it looks like the book uses inverters (NOT gates) in the example because they're the **most basic logic cell**.

Suppose we would use not an inverter but a **buffer**. In all CMOS logic technologies (and that is 99.99% of what is used today) a buffer is made by cascading two inverters:

[image]
[Source](https://itectec.com/electrical/electronic-logic-buffer-design/)

Where Tr1 and Tr2 are an inverter and also Tr3 and Tr4, like this single inverter:

[image]
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_(logic_gate))

So if you would use buffers instead of NOT gates, you would need the double amount of inverters (4 instead of 2).

I think the point that the book wants to make is easier to explain using NOT gates as they're simpler.

> Is it aimed to amplify the signal?

Yes and a buffer would also do that.

In the case that you want to avoid inverting the signal, you could also use buffers as the transmitter and the receiver.

Comment: thanks a lot! I think I understand it now.